# writing data to debugfs --- from a device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

With proc we can easily use read & write system call as shown in this example.
[write on /proc entry through user space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863005/write-on-proc-entry-through-user-space)

But i am working on passing information from driver to user-space using debugfs. 
I am able to find these two example code. Here application is able to read and write to debugfs file using mmap() system call.

- http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/code/mmap_simple_kernel.c
- http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/code/mmap_user.c

But suppose in my case requirement for communicating using Debugfs file with device driver:

```
user-space application    <-------> debugfs file <-------> Device driver
```

1. So can i use same code mmap_simple_kernel.c inside my --->> device driver code  --->> and transfer data to debugfs directly from driver ? But in this case there will be two file_operations structures inside my driver will it cause some problem ? Is it right approach ?
2. Or just like application is following process in -- mmap_user.c  --- same process -- i follow in my device driver program. And keep mmap_simple_kernel.c  as seprate module for debugfs entry ?

Comment: You can use `read()` and `write()` on a file in debugfs too if you need that. `mmap()` comes in handy if you need to pass larger amounts of data, for example, but it is not mandatory to use it.

Comment: In one of my projects, I use debugfs files to provide some data to the user space and to control my kernel-space system, see, for example, [this file](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/source/browse/sources/core/resolve_ip.c). Three files are created there in debugfs (_"i_addr"_, _"func_name"_ and _"func_i_start"_), the 1st one is writable, the remaining two are read-only. See also how `debugfs_create_file()` is used there. I would also suggest to see other [debugfs_create_\* functions](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/debugfs.h), they may better suit your needs.

Comment: As for another example of using `mmap()`, the links are [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501527/ioctl-vs-netlink-vs-memmap-to-communicate-between-kernel-space-and-user-space#comment15219915_11501527). Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at how kmemleak uses debugfs in mm/kmemleak.c:

```
static const struct seq_operations kmemleak_seq_ops = {
        .start = kmemleak_seq_start,
        .next  = kmemleak_seq_next,
        .stop  = kmemleak_seq_stop,
        .show  = kmemleak_seq_show,
};

static int kmemleak_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
        return seq_open(file, &kmemleak_seq_ops);
}

static int kmemleak_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
        return seq_release(inode, file);
}

static ssize_t kmemleak_write(struct file *file, const char __user *user_buf,
                              size_t size, loff_t *ppos)
{...}

static const struct file_operations kmemleak_fops = {
        .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
        .open           = kmemleak_open,
        .read           = seq_read,
        .write          = kmemleak_write,
        .llseek         = seq_lseek,
        .release        = kmemleak_release,
};


dentry = debugfs_create_file("kmemleak", S_IRUGO, NULL, NULL,
                             &kmemleak_fops);
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is the top search result in Google for mmap debugfs. I am adding here an important information. According to this https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/5/21/73 post debugfs_create_file() in the kernel 4.8.0 or higher will ignore .mmap field in the struct file_operations

Use debugfs_create_file_unsafe() as a workaround