# debugfs -- ring buffer implementation -- linux

Tags: embedded-linux, interrupt-handling

I am first time trying debugfs to transfer data from the kernel to the user space. Please suggest how to proceed in this regard.

I do not want to use tty driver. It is just for practice from my side. Actually i am trying to write my kernel driver for USART where interrupt data will be pushed to user-space application using debugfs ring buffer.

Long before i found a post by a fellow Stackexchange friend to his GIT repository -- where he had implemented debugfs as ring buffer ... but that link is lost to me... so not able to find some refrence to proced in this regard.

Please suggest.

Comment: i know few links which i tried from eugene :---

Answer (score 0):

i know few links which i tried from eugene :---

[ioctl vs netlink vs memmap to communicate between kernel space and user space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501527/ioctl-vs-netlink-vs-memmap-to-communicate-between-kernel-space-and-user-space#comment15219915_11501527)
[writing data to debugfs --- from a device driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079893/writing-data-to-debugfs-from-a-device-driver)
http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/source/browse/sources/core/resolve_ip.c

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [netlink](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356) .

> Netlink socket is a special IPC used for transferring information
>   between kernel and user-space processes. It provides a full-duplex
>   communication link between the two by way of standard socket APIs for
>   user-space processes and a special kernel API for kernel modules.